# How to update zen from 7x-5x to 7x-6x?

Tags: upgrading, theming

I'm trying to do css updates on a zen subtheme developed on zen 7.56. I'm having trouble to get compass running on my development machine because of a gem conflict between some of the compass dependencies. I'd like to move to zen 7.6 to be able to use libsass and gulp. So, I have the following questions:
1) theme was developed using compass and compass mixins, can I use the old scss files? Or will I have to identify and update the scss?
2) what else do I need to think about upgrading a theme between versions?

Comment: I'm curious if you found an answer...

Comment: Not yet, took the lazy man route for the short term and just edited the CSS the boring way